Differentiating Dirac delta with product rule
I have here an equation.
$$
h'(t_2) \delta(t_1 - t_2) = [h(t_2) - h(t_1)] \delta'(t_1 - t_2)
$$
I checked the equality by integrating both sides with a test function.
$$
\int d t_1 \phi(t_1) \ldots \to h'(t_2) \phi(t_2) \\
\int d t_2 \phi(t_2) \ldots \to h'(t_1) \phi(t_1) 
$$
Is this equation mathematically correct? I see a very similar derivation in this answer. If correct, can this kind of equation be derived using some sort of product rule? Checking using test functions may not be very practical for more complicated expressions. E.g.
$$
h'(t_1) \delta(t_1 - t_3) = \int d t_2 h(t_2) [\delta'(t_1 - t_2) \delta(t_2 - t_3) - \delta(t_1 - t_2) \delta'(t_2 - t_3)]
$$

For $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ and $h\in C^\infty$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\langle h'_{t_2}\delta_{t_2},\phi \rangle&=\langle \delta_{t_2},h'_{t_2}\phi \rangle\\\\
&=h'(t_2)\phi(t_2)\tag1
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\langle h_{t_2}\delta'_{t_2},\phi \rangle&=\langle \delta'_{t_2},h_{t_2}\phi \rangle\\\\
&=-h(t_2)\phi'(t_2)\tag2
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\langle h\delta'_{t_2},\phi \rangle&=\langle \delta'_{t_2},h\phi \rangle\\\\
&=-h'(t_2)\phi(t_2)-h(t_2)\phi'(t_2)\tag3
\end{align}$$
Subtracting $(3)$ from $(2)$ yields $(1)$.  And we are done!

Thanks. Do we also need to check with test functions of the $t_1$ variable? Or that is not necessary?

You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And  that is not necessary, but would be a nice exercise for practice.

Start with $h(t_1) \delta(t_1 - t_2) = h(t_2) \delta(t_1 - t_2)$. Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $t_1$ using the product rule
$$
h'(t_1) \delta(t_1-t_2) + h(t_1) \delta'(t_1 -t_2) = h(t_2) \delta'(t_1-t_2)
$$
